# Calculate mean above certain threshold for each column

Tags: matlab

My data is in a nxm array named x. What I want to do is calculate the average of the values in each of the columns above a certain threshold. So the output should be a 1xm vector.

mean(x) obviously does this without specifying a threshold.
`mean(x>70)` performs a truth check and basically returns the percentage of values above the threshold for each column

You could define a new variable as such

```
y = x > 70
```

and then

```
mean(x(y))
```

but this returns the average over all the columns of x.

There's a very cumbersome way of doing it by having a line of code for every column.

```
mean(x(y(1:end,1)))
```

And so on, but this is obviously ugly.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here. Hopefully someone will be able to help out.

Comment: Is the threshold identical for each column?

Comment: Yes it is identical

Comment: Then in the solution below, just set `threshold` to a scalar; i.e. `threshold = 70`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten that you can multiply the mask through element-wise

```
threshold = []; %define threshold here; it can be a 1xm vector or a scalar.
output = sum(x.*(x>threshold))./sum(x>threshold);
```

Comment: What that does though is changing all the elements of x that are below the threshold to 0, which in turn heavily skews done the average. So, that's not really a good option in this case.

Comment: Ah, oversight on my part. This has been corrected by dividing the column-wise sum by the number of elements above the threshold in each column, rather than using the `mean()` command

Comment: Yep, this is it. Thanks a lot!